# “Mass in Special Relativity” misconception

Tags: discussion, answers, reputation

“Unification of energy and mass ”, when explained carelessly, becomes one of the most dangerous heresies. Ī don’t point my finger to anybody, but many otherwise knowledgeable guys easily write a rubbish with roughly “Special Relativity abolished the difference between energy  and mass, hallelujah Einstein, hallelujah *E* = *m* *c*<sup>2</sup> ” meaning. Of course we, “adult” guys, understand that Special Relativity actually *separated* two masses:

- An essence susceptible to forces and creating gravitational forces (the same as energy or, if you like, 4-momentum *vector* or its projection).
- Mass, an **intrinsic** quantitative property of a body (said the *rest mass* or, more generally, *invariant mass*, the *magnitude* of 4-momentum).

They are, of course, related, but are not more the same thing than “distance” and “length” are.

My proposal: any answer suggesting “energy and mass are the same thing” without any specification about **which definition of mass is assumed** ought to be summarily downvoted on sight. The same about “photons do not effect gravity” visionaries.

---

Update: answers like [What keeps mass from turning into energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91501/what-keeps-mass-from-turning-into-energy/91503#91503) were assumed, although it is hard to find this misconception in such concentrated form on psysics.SE. And it likely became a moot question for now.

Comment: If you think such answers are incorrect, why not post a correct answer? Or at least a comment pointing out *why* the answer is wrong.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos but what do **you** think? Is “hallelujah *E* = *m* *c* ² ” stuff helpful for students, or it corrupts their minds?

Comment: Except no one around here *says* E=mc^2 is right; most every answerer says E^2=p^2c^2+m^2c^4 is to use.

Comment: Good point about *E²* = *p² c²* + *m² c⁴* ; Ī’ll think on it.

Comment: Although voting is *completely* up to the discretion of individual users, every answer that you know to be wrong should be downvoted by you. You're proposing nothing new, unless I missed something.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: a link (either at meta or the main site) with an analysis of hallelujah-Einstein syndrome and proposed remedies, please?

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that the "solution" to this is that the SE model is inherently built on the assumption that wrong answers will be downvoted and good answers will be upvoted. Since the posts you talk about *are* wrong, they should be downvoted and no one believe them. I understand the problem, I just don't think we have another solution to this (I'm going to crawl around the network a bot and see if I can find something more authoritative on this).

Comment: @ACuriousMind: you miss a subtle gap between “(demonstrably) wrong” and “mind-corrupting half-truth”.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: On a completely separate topic, why does your pronoun I feature an over-line on it (or is it just my computer)? E.g., *Ī don’t point my finger...*

Comment: @Kyle Kanos: now in my profile.

Comment: Offhand I don't recall reams of answers saying that mass and energy are the same thing. Can you edit your question to give us some examples?

Comment: @JohnRennie I think the entire realm of cosmology acts as though mass is energy. It also acts as though everything else is a form of mass by having everything in mass dimensions. Energy is measured in mass, time and position in inverse mass, acceleration is in mass, forces are in squared mass, etc. So at least you *could* say cosmologists tend to observe no significant distinction between energy and mass

Comment: @Jim: yes, I agree, but that's specific to General Relativity because (as usually written) $T_{00}$ is the energy density and mass is counted as energy. However the post is about Special Relativity. It isn't clear to me that SR has much to say about mass unless by SR you mean quantum field theory.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi 2 things, but I'll start with what I see as most important. 1) Why do you want a serif font so badly? Serifs, like with Times, increase the speed at which people read over your words. Don't you want a nice sans-serif to make people slow down and take in your words more carefully? 2) Barring the odd exception to the rule, I don't think the experts on this site tend to spout half-truths that corrupt the minds of the learning. And when teaching science, it can be helpful to teach something wrong now and correct later. Like teaching the model of the atom.

Comment: @JohnRennie no, I'm just throwing in my two-cents without fully reading into what the issue is. I tend to do that even though I know I shouldn't

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: That serif issue doesn't really make sense to me. Especially given the **every** major browser (Firefox, Chrome, Safari & Opera) allow you to *change the fonts for yourself*.

Comment: -1 for trolling.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, and on a complete sidetrack, what does "_hallelujah_" mean?

Comment: @New_new_newbie: It's a [Leonard Cohen song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallelujah_(Leonard_Cohen_song)) :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie - Ohh! Thanks :)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8610/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143652/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5):

I have to confess that I don't understand the distinction between the two types of masses made by the OP. I certainly agree that mass and energy are not the same, though they are interchangeable. However a more detailed discussion of the issue is probably inappropriate for the meta.

My main point is that the tone of the post strikes me as inappropriate. No-one is paid for contributing to this site. We do so entirely out of good will. I don't like the idea of punishing members for answers. Unless an answer is obviously lazy or careless the correct response to a misleading answer is to (tactfully) point out the error and/or post a better answer yourself. Answering questions is just as much a learning process as posting them, and few of us can claim all our answers are beyond improvement.

I note Incnis' profile states:

> This site is supposedly useful for “active researchers, academics and students of physics”. If you want science, then never rely on such self-governed Internet sites (Stack Exchange, Wikipedia, or whatever), that are not supervised by an academic organization. They are all flawed. You can find some valuable insights here, but you may not trust assessments made by this community. Use reputable sources, available experts, and your own intellect to verify all this stuff.

Well yes, but that applies to everything in life and academic organizations are far from beyond reproach. I think the Physics SE stands head and shoulders above any comparable site I have ever seen. It is everything that peer review should be.

**Re the [edit to the question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/6248/revisions):** I wouldn't use phrases like:

> It's not that mass and energy "can change back and forth". They are literally equivalent ways of talking about the same thing

though a minor edit to *they are different forms of the same thing* would be fine by me, and I'd guess that's what the author really meant. However I think far worse crimes against physics are committed. Is this really such a big issue as to warrant its own meta post?

Comment: John’s “punishing members for answers” was a misinterpretation. The objective is to shun *a concrete answer*, not to shut up and drive away a person who (once) wrote the gibberish, possibly in good faith.

Comment: Ī made a point that **there is no “simply mass” is relativity,** that generalization attempts are either misleading (4-momentum projection) or short of properties we accustomed to (invariant mass). Could John Rennie write a posting on physics.SE that criticizes this thing and/or endorses the  “mass”-written-“invariant”-assumed approach?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: I don't lie awake at night worrying whether students may be getting the wrong impression of what mass is, so I feel no strong desire to write a blog post on the subject. If you wish to do so I'd be interested to see it because I still don't understand what your point is.

Comment: How do you understand “different forms”? “⟨ *ψ* ∣ *ψ* ⟩” and “‖ *ψ* ‖² ” are demonstrably *different forms of the same thing,* whereas invariant mass and energy⋲momentum are **different concepts,** like length and distance, or action and angular momentum.